# Will creating an index improve performance on a full scan

Tags: sql-server-2005

Will adding an index on a Large data warehouse table (8Million rows, 200+ column) make any difference to the query time if all I am doing is selecting all rows from the table ?
Thanks

Comment: Index has additional costs of maintenance when inserts, updates and deletes happen - fragmentation, disk space, etc. If you think that the cost is ok then create it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your data is stored as either a heap or a clustered index, with all of it that structure.

If your data is in a heap and you create a clustered index, then you will reorganise all that data into a tree structure, and you will leverage some of the nicer aspects of clustered indexes, such as ordered data, and (unlike heaps) data without forwarding records (which can slow down scans). The data will be about the same size though.

If you create a non-clustered index, then this is a COPY of some of the data. This can help if you're getting only a subset of the columns or rows. If your non-clustered index doesn't include all the columns that you need for your query, it probably won't get used. But if you're only wanting three columns in your query, and your index has all three, you can save quite a bit of effort. You might get 100 times as many rows onto each page on disk, and scanning this index should therefore take just 1% of the effort.

Having indexes is just like in paper-based systems. If all you need is a list of names, then you can put all that on a single page instead of using the filing cabinet that has a dossier on each person. You'll have to maintain that list, but it might be worthwhile with the savings in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index will help if you're using an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you're not ordering the data (i.e. you're using `SELECT * FROM TABLE`), then SQL Server can very quickly scan through the table and dump the data straight out over the network.

If you are ordering the data (e.g. `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY UserID`), SQL Server will need to take an extra step to sort the data before sending it back to you. This can be very expensive - if the data size is sufficiently large, SQL Server will need to use a temporary table (in the tempdb) to perform the sort.

On the other hand, if you have an index on your `ORDER BY` column (e.g. UserID), SQL Server no longer has to sort the data. It can use the index - which is already sorted - and then for each row in the index, it will go and find the full record from the table and send it through to you.

As Kin mentioned, indexes have additional costs, and this can really add up (especially in terms of disk space) for a big table.

It seems unusual to me that you'd be selecting all rows from a table with 8 million rows! If you're using it for analysis, you might want to consider putting some of your logic into the SQL Statement, and let the database engine do some of your work.

Comment: [Here's an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ea7b/1) showing the difference in behaviour. Once you run the SQL you can use the "Show Execution Plan" link to see how SQL Server performs the query, then you can uncomment the `CREATE INDEX` and see the difference.